# How to set up source control in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, version-control

I want to set up source control for my project, but it seems like I need a server for this. I've never done this before, and I couldn't find anything helpfull yet.

Is there any way to host a server locally so Visual studio can use it? Or do you know any online (free) servers I can use?

By the way, if source control is not actually what i should use for keeping track of changes in my files, please suggest a better option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of solutions to this problem.

A simple way to go is use subversion.... get tortiseSVN,  and you can make a local repository  ( you don't need to run any kind of server software ).

Then get something like Ankh SVN for Visual Studio

All free software!

Answer (score 1):

You need to [pick a source control provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software), such as [Team Foundation Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server), [Perforce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce), or [GIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29).

You can then install a server on your machine, install a Visual Studio plugin (not applicable for TFS), and connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your VS2010 licence through a MSDN subscription, then you have a licence to TFS, see: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/11/02/License-costs-of-Team-Foundation-Server-2010.aspx